# How do I insert a hyperlink to another page with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, itext

I would like to add a link to an existing pdf that jumps to a coordinate on another page.

I am able to add a rectangle using this code:

```
PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,100,100,0);
rectangle.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
overContent.Rectangle(rectangle);
stamper.Close();
```

How can I do similar to create a link that is clickable?  Thanks.

Comment: Consider to mark accepted answer or comment on existing why they are not an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in chapter 7 of the book ["iText in Action - Second Edition"](http://itextpdf.com/book/). You can find an example here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=150

If you need the C# version, please take a look here: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx

More specifically: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter07&ex=TimetableAnnotations2

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(
    stamper.Writer, rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
    new PdfAction("http://itextpdf.com/")
);
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

In this code sample `page` is the number of the page where you want to add the link and `rect` is the `Rectangle` object defining the coordinates on that page.

Answer (score 1):

I like building my PDFs with tables and this is the code I use

```
PdfPCell cell = new Chunk anchor = new Chunk("Name of link", font);
anchor.SetAnchor("PageName.aspx");
cell.AddElement(new Phrase(anchor));
cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; 
cell.Padding = 5;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

or if you want it borderless

```
PdfPCell cell = new Chunk anchor = new Chunk("Name of link", font);
anchor.SetAnchor("PageName.aspx");
cell.AddElement(new Phrase(anchor));
cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
table.AddCell(cell);
```