# How to give a Linkaction to button in pdf using itextsharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to build a interactive pdf. Where i created three buttons in abc.pdf using iTextsharp.

I have three different pdf

1.Customer details.pdf

2.Some Transaction details.pdf

3.Chart graph.pdf.

When i click on first button in abc.pdf how it navigate a customer details.pdf to a abc.pdf page where buttons are there.and has same as first button,when i click second button navigate a transaction detailes.pdf and third button click navigate chart graph pdf .If some one could guide me. i am using itextsharp 5.5.8.

Comment: Are you merging three PDFs together and you just want to [add links to those pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13448853/231316) or are you making a [PDF Portfolio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9833572/231316)?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. yes, we are building a home page with multiple buttons to call other pdf's. I actually can create a page with multiple buttons but when i click those buttons it must land to the targeted PDF. If you could guide me in doing this first. Secondly,  I do not understand what is PDF Portfolio, if you could guide me about this with sample.